# Cannot create a new device in AVD Device Definitions

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, android-virtual-device

I am using Ubuntu Linux machine when code Android applications. When I start the AVD and want to create a custom Device Definition, nothing happens when I click on the "Create Device" button. I remember this was possible in the past, but at some point it stopped working. I cannot determine when exactly it stopped working.

[image]

The data on the image are bogus ones, but the definition should be created.

I have gone thru all similar topics on SE, I have updated SDK components, but the new definition still cannot be created.

Does anyone have any idea? I am out of ideas.